# PHP Database Connection with null host variable

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$host = ""; <<------------------ Empty
$username = "root";
$password = "";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;db=tesssst", $username, $password);
    echo "Connection succes";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

why php still can connect to server with empty host?

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation on this, but I believe PDO uses 'localhost' as host when no host is provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The host is the database name. It can't be empty. By default, the name of host is "localhost".

Comment: Is the default host name the database name or 'localhost'?